# woocommerce registeration form edit email field

Tags: php, wordpress, email, input, woocommerce

please any one can help me customize the
[registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soYDP.jpg) of woocommerce plugin and can edit the code to let user only enter specific email domain names such like @ 'fdu.edu.jo' how to do that

that's the code of email field  **woocommerce plugin** --> **form-login.php** file

```
<p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
       <input type="text" name="email" id="reg_email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ) : ''; ?>" />
</p>
```

I found that code but I don't know where to put it exactly

```
<?php if (preg_match('|@onlyalloweddomain.com$|', $registrantMailAddress;  ?>
```

thanks in advance and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I just made this and it works perfectly , is that solution right

```
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[g-u]+\.[d-u]+\.[j-o]{2}$" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ) : ''; ?>" />
        </p>
```